# Angular w/Jest: `verify()` vs.`expectOne()`?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I have a failing test that I'm not sure how to fix. The error messages I'm getting from Jest appear to be contradictory, and the problem relates to the behavior of two [Angular HttpTestingController](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController) methods: `verify()` and `expectOne()`.

The test in question, in the context of its file:

```
import {TestBed, getTestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {PrintProjectsService} from './print-projects.service';
import {AppConfig} from '../../app.config';

describe('PrintProjectsService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: PrintProjectsService;
  let appConfig: AppConfig;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [PrintProjectsService, AppConfig]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(PrintProjectsService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    appConfig = injector.get(AppConfig);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  //This test passes
  it('should make a GET request to retrieve a printable factory when provided a printable factory id', () => {
    const id = '12345';
    service.getPrintableFactory(id).subscribe();
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${appConfig.API_URL}/api/printed-book/v1/printable-factories/${id}/`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  });

  // This is the one that fails
  it('should make a GET request to retrieve cover image data from the cover service', () => {
    const imageType = 'full';
    service.getCoverImage(12345, '0850X1100FCSTDCO080CW444GXX', imageType).subscribe();
    //httpMock.verify(); //this finds a GET at undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${appConfig.API_URL}/cover/api/cover-images/${imageType}`);
    expect(req.request.responseType).toBe('blob');
  });
});
```

Jest returns this error message:

```
● PrintProjectsService › should make a GET request to retrieve cover image data from the cover service

Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full", found none.

  44 |     service.getCoverImage(12345, '0850X1100FCSTDCO080CW444GXX', imageType).subscribe();
> 45 |     const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${appConfig.API_URL}/cover/api/cover-images/${imageType}`);
  46 |     expect(req.request.responseType).toBe('blob');

  at HttpClientTestingBackend.Object.<anonymous>.HttpClientTestingBackend.expectOne (node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http-testing.umd.js:435:19)
  at src/app/services/print-projects/print-projects.service.spec.ts:45:26
  ...
  at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:50:27)

● PrintProjectsService › should make a GET request to retrieve cover image data from the cover service

Expected no open requests, found 1: GET undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full

  23 |   afterEach(() => {
> 24 |     httpMock.verify();
  25 |   });
```

The fact that the URL variables render to `undefined` in the error messages is irrelevant - that's the case within the passing tests as well.

What's confusing me is that when `expectOne()` is reached within the test, no request can be found for `undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full`, but after the test, `verify()` finds a GET request at the *identical* URL: `undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full`. `verify()` also finds a GET request at `undefined/cover/api/cover-images/full` when placed within the test on the line before `expectOne()`.

Why doesn't `expectOne()` catch the request but `verify()` does? Is the error message not telling me everything I need? I seem to be getting the same error messages back regardless of whether I run `jest` or `jest --verbose`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the issue with a variant of `expectOne()` gleaned from here: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/master/example/src/app/service/hero.service.spec.ts#L59

Here is the new, passing version of the test:

```
it('should make a GET request to retrieve cover image data from the cover service', () => {
    const imageType = 'full';
    service.getCoverImage(12345, '0850X1100FCSTDCO080CW444GXX', imageType).subscribe();
    const req = httpMock.expectOne((request: HttpRequest<Blob>) => {
      return request.url === `${appConfig.API_URL}/cover/api/cover-images/${imageType}`;
    });
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    // the original `expect()` below also passes, but since we already state that the request will return a Blob above, the `expect()` above is a better option
    // expect(req.request.responseType).toBe('blob'); 
  });
```

It appears as though the `url` match-only version of `expectOne()`, as was being used originally, expects a `JSON` response by default. In any case, the `Blob` response type of this particular call appears to have been the source of the problem.